# JavaFx - TableView: How to use custom Comparator<T> for sorting?

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

... where `T` is the generic type of the `TableView`.

I'm implementing a file-listview with three columns, so far. Each of type `java.nio.file.Path`. For the name column, I wrote a `Comparator<Path>` which sorts the files with directories-first and case-insensitiv. The other two comparators sort by last-modified-time and file-size. For this they compare on `long` fields.

But the `comparatorProperty` of a column is based on `Comparator<String>`. Which, I think, sorts based on the displayed text...

**So I have to find a way, to use the sort-on-header-click feature with the type of the `TableView`?**

Comment: Can you post some code? I don't really understand what the types of your `TableView` and `TableColumn`s are. `TableView<Path>`, `TableColumn<Path, Path>`, `TableColumn<Path, FileTime>`, `TableColumn<Path, Long>` would be the obvious choices but these don't seem to match your description.

Comment: looks like you simply mis-read the api doc ... can't see a comparator<String> , it's [comparator<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#comparatorProperty) with T being the type of the column data :-)

Comment: You're both right. I misunderstood the description of ```T``` parameter in ```TableColumnBase<S, T>```. So I had ```TableColumn<Path, String>```, instead of ```TableColumn<Path, Path>```, for example. After I had changed this, I could use ```Comparator<Path>```. Thank you. :)

Comment: you might consider answering and accepting your own question - the solution is easier to find for future readers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use wrong type parameters, when creating your `TableColumn`. If you create a `TableColumn<Path, Path>`, you can specify a `Comparator<Path>` for that column. Likewise `TableColumn<Path, FileTime>` and `TableColumn<Path, Long>` to use `Comparator<FileTime>` and `Comparator<Long>`.

*From the docs:*

```
Class TableColumnBase<S,T>
Type Parameters:
S - The type of the UI control (e.g. the type of the 'row').
T - The type of the content in all cells in this table column.
```